# Relation between roots an coefficients in a generic equation: $a_0+a_1\cdot x+\cdots+a_n\cdot x^n$

Tags: polynomials

In a generic equation $$a_0\cdot x+a_1\cdot x^2+ a_3\cdot x^3+\cdots+a_n\cdot x^n$$ there are some relations between roots ($x_1, x_2,\ldots,x_n$) and coefficients ($a_0, a_1,\ldots,a_n$). How can i demonstrate these relations or Viete's formulas? 
These are the relations:
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+\cdots+x_n= -\frac{a_{n-1}} {a_n}$$
$$(x_1\cdot x_2+x_1\cdot x_3+\cdots+x_1\cdot x_n)(x_2\cdot x_3+ x_2\cdot x_4+\cdots+x_2\cdot x_n)+\cdots+x_{n-1}\cdot x_n= \frac{a_{n-2}}{a_n}$$
$$x_1\cdot x_2\cdot \cdot \cdot x_n=(-1)^n\frac{a_0}{a_n}$$
I have no idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:** You can writte $p(x)=a_0+a_1\cdot x+\cdots +a_n\cdot x^n$ as

$$p(x)=a_n(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\cdots(x-x_n)$$

Where $x_1,...,x_n$ are the roots of $p(x)$. Expanding this expression and comparing coefficients should give you the relations.